# Adding ngram to solr schema and rebuilding the index

Tags: solr

Im trying to add ngram filter to my existing schema to enable substring search...

The current solr index has 10 million rows...If I add this change to schema. Do I need to rebuild the index?

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reindex for the change to be effective on already-indexed documents. EdgeNGramTokenFilter works by breaking tokens into n-grams and indexing each n-gram, and this can only be done at indexing time. If you don't reindex Solr will *work* but you won't get proper substring search.

In general, anytime you change the analyzer for a field you need to reindex. Often Solr will break or produce incorrect search results if the current schema doesn't match the one used during indexing. If you can reindex without a lot of pain, that's going to be a lot easier than digging in and figuring out why Solr is misbehaving after a schema change.